# Secure comunication Between a Web Page and the Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, security, httphandler

I'm wondering if theres already a combo let say jQuery - Some C# DLL to proive a secure both way communication between ASPX forms with jQuery and a control layer based on ashx files with C# classes...

---

**[From comment below]**
Well I see I have to be more specific. The are things like sniffers on simple network analysis tools even like Firebug that let you see the data transfered via POST or GET. The idea to secure a Server Client application is to ensure that data isn't corrupt and compromised, and to achive that you have to make imposible to an atacker to report false info so the best is to have improved some cryptographyc algorithms both on client and server to crypt decrypt encode decode data...

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Well I see I have to be more specific. The are things like sniffers on simple network analysis tools even like Firebug that let you see the data transfered via POST or GET. The idea to secure a Server Client application is to ensure that data isn't corrupt and compromised, and to achive that you have to make imposible to an atacker to report false info so the best is to have improved some cryptographyc algorithms both on client and server to crypt decrypt encode decode data...

Comment: it sounds like you just need SSL.  The comment by James Deville in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664255/strength-of-rsa-encrypting-an-aes-key) seems like good advice!

Comment: You just need to use SSL.

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can ever make web communication secure between a client and a server is by using SSL.

Comment: Wrong.  Also, SSL might not help.

Comment: I'm looking for a combo of classes - scripts in both sides jQuery C# like AES support for jQuery and C# or Base64 or a custom algorithm but with support in jQuery (Client Side) and ASPX C# (Server Side)

Comment: If he's trying to protect against end-users, SSL won't help at all.

Comment: Perhaps I'm totally wrong, but just encrypting messages to go back and forth is still vulnerable to MITM attacks.  Digital signing would be needed in order to prevent this - and then you might as well just use SSL?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/) is a Javascript AES engine.

However, you **really** should use SSL instead.

Comment: Wouldn't that be moot, as the client AND server would need the key to enc/dec the data. And thus the key would have to be transmitted to the client.

Comment: I'm just giving him what he asked for.  You're right that it's probably a bad idea.  However, if the key is a salted hash of a password entered on the client, it could be reasonably secure